# boost::asio internal threads

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

When using boost::asio for some asynchronous TCP  communication I noticed it starts a lot of (3-4) internal threads. Reading in [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html), it says

```
"The implementation of this library for a particular platform may 
 make use of one or more internal threads to emulate asynchronicity"
```

Now my lib has very strict requirements to not start any extra threads (except one that is supplied by the client and which now starts `io_service::run()`). Is there any way to stop boost::asio from creating these extra threads?

Alternatively, is there any other async library out there that can run in only one thread?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can disable the emulated asynchronous operation support by defining `BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_THREADS` in the appropriate translation units. [The documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/using.html) has this to say about the definition

> Explicitly disables Boost.Asio's threading
>   support, independent of whether or not Boost as a whole supports
>   threads.

If you didn't find the [platform specific implementation notes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/implementation.html), it clearly states which operations use this emulation. For example I know on nearly every platform `async_resolve()` is emulated in this fashion, the thread is created upon the first invocation of `async_resolve()`. Some (all?) Windows platforms emulate several other operations such as `deadline_timer` operations.

One alternative to disabling threading support might be to avoid these emulated operations. I personally have not used `BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_THREADS` in a project so I'm unsure if it has other side effects.

Comment: When `BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_THREADS` is defined, Asio throws a `boost::asio::error::operation_not_supported` error when it attempts to spawn a thread.  Thus, the only option is to avoid thread spawning operations.  On most implementations, this can be done by using `resolve()` instead of `async_resolve()`.  On Windows, defining `BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_IOCP` will cause Asio to use the select-based implementation, which is slower but should not spawn additional threads.

Comment: Thanks, indeed I did not find this documentation at all. I will try with DISABLE_IOCP

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually tested it to see if threads are spawned on your particular platform?  If none are, problem solved!  If some are, you might consider a different library like libevent or libev.  Either of those, or a whole bunch of other async event loops provided by various libraries like Qt, could work.

Comment: Yes I have seen that they spawn. Also this lib is ported to many platforms