# Boost Asio experimental channel poor performance

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I wrote the following code to analyze the performance of the experimental channel in Asio within a single-threaded application. On i7-6700HQ@3.2GHz, it takes around 1 second to complete, demonstrating a throughput of approximately 3M items per second.

The problem might be due to the fact that asio is in single-threaded mode, causing the producer to signal the consumer part and leading to immediate resumption of the consumer coroutine on every call to async_send(). However, I'm unsure how to test to confirm if this is the case and how to avoid it in real applications. Reducing the channel buffer size, even to 0, has no effect on the throughput, which might be for the same reason.

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/awaitable_operators.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/channel.hpp>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace asio::experimental::awaitable_operators;
using channel_t = asio::experimental::channel< void(boost::system::error_code, uint64_t) >;

asio::awaitable< void >
producer(channel_t &ch)
{
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < 3'000'000; i++)
        co_await ch.async_send(boost::system::error_code {}, i, asio::use_awaitable);

    ch.close();
}

asio::awaitable< void >
consumer(channel_t &ch)
{
    for (;;)
        co_await ch.async_receive(asio::use_awaitable);
}

asio::awaitable< void >
experiment()
{
    channel_t ch { co_await asio::this_coro::executor, 1000 };
    co_await (consumer(ch) && producer(ch));
}
int
main()
{
    asio::io_context ctx {};
    asio::co_spawn(ctx, experiment(), asio::detached);
    ctx.run();
}
```

Comment: I think I've seen you post a better performant version on cppslack (using try_read). Could you post it? The world deserves to know

Answer (score 3):

You can save a little by providing hints about the threading:

- provide concurrency hint unsafe ([`BOOST_ASIO_CONCURRENCY_HINT_UNSAFE`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/concurrency_hint.html))
- optionally disabling all threading - this will in practice probably not matter, it's just possible as long as you don't need any services that employ [internal threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14983337/85371))
- avoiding type erasure on the executor; this means replacing `any_io_executor` with the concrete executor type that you employ

I wrote a side-by-side benchmark with reduced message-count (30k) so that Nonius can sample 100 runs and do statistical analysis on the results:

```
//#define TWEAKS

#ifdef TWEAKS
#define BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_THREADS 1
#endif

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/awaitable_operators.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/channel.hpp>

#include <iostream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;

using namespace asio::experimental::awaitable_operators;
using boost::system::error_code;

using context    = asio::io_context;
#ifdef TWEAKS
using executor_t = context::executor_type;
using channel_t  = asio::experimental::channel<executor_t, void(error_code, uint64_t)>;
#else
using executor_t = asio::any_io_executor;
using channel_t  = asio::experimental::channel<void(error_code, uint64_t)>;
#endif

asio::awaitable<void> producer(channel_t& ch) {
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < 30'000; i++)
        co_await ch.async_send(error_code {}, i, asio::use_awaitable);

    ch.close();
}

asio::awaitable<void> consumer(channel_t& ch) {
    for (;;)
        co_await ch.async_receive(asio::use_awaitable);
}

asio::awaitable<void> experiment() {
    asio::any_io_executor ex = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;
    channel_t ch { *ex.target<executor_t>(), 1000 };
    co_await (consumer(ch) && producer(ch));
}

void foo() {
    try {
#ifdef TWEAKS
        asio::io_context ctx{BOOST_ASIO_CONCURRENCY_HINT_UNSAFE};
#else
        asio::io_context ctx{1};
#endif

        asio::co_spawn(ctx, experiment(), asio::detached);

        ctx.run();
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}

#include <nonius/benchmark.h++>
#define NONIUS_RUNNER
#include <nonius/main.h++>

NONIUS_BENCHMARK( //
    "foo",        //
    [](nonius::chronometer cm) { cm.measure([] { foo(); }); })
```

The results per 30k batch (including construction and teardown) are:

- Without TWEAKS: mean 12.091 ± 0.233ms ([full data graph](http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/5aed3ce6-f147-41e7-9be1-e1db1e873307/normal.html))
- With TWEAKS defined: mean 8.784±0.097ms ([full data graph](http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/2297dd53-2395-4b87-89df-cbb1019055cb/tweaked.html))

So ~25% speed increase, and also much reduced variance.

Combining the [series in one graph](https://plotly.com/%7Esehe/29/):

[image]

### Thoughts

These are just the Asio technical tweaks. I might be missing some still.

I suspect you should be able to get much better throughput with smart buffering. I'm assuming you need the Asio integration for other reasons, making this the right choice.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that the consumer and producer sides are rescheduled on each send/receive operation; that's why the channel size has no effect on the throughput.
I've made the following changes to the code, and now it can send 90M per second. However, this is what I expected from the implementation.

```
 asio::awaitable< void >
 producer(channel_t &ch)
 {
     for (uint64_t i = 0; i < 90'000'000; i++)
     {
         if (!ch.try_send(boost::system::error_code {}, i))
             co_await ch.async_send(boost::system::error_code {}, i, asio::use_awaitable);
     }
 
     ch.close();
 }
 
 asio::awaitable< void >
 consumer(channel_t &ch)
 {
     for (;;)
     {
         if (!ch.try_receive([](auto, auto) {}))
             co_await ch.async_receive(asio::use_awaitable);
     }
 }
```

I believe the reason why this is not the default behavior of channels is that awaitables in Asio have no way to return true in the await_ready() call, so they always have to suspend and initiate an asynchronous operation.